# Fixing Exception: AWTException Incompatible with Throws Clause When Using Robot Function in Child Class

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation

Whenever i'm using the Robot function in the child class this exception occures `[Exception AWTException is not compatible with throws clause in basic_methods.main(String[])]`

```java
package Window_Handling;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;

import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

import base_methods.basic_methods;

public class window_handling_Robot_notes extends basic_methods {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException {
        browserLaunch("chrome");
        urlGo("https://demo.nopcommerce.com/");
        Actions mouse = new Actions(driver);  
        
        Robot Keyboard = new Robot();

    }

}
```